# Pyautogui en RDP

Tags: python

Llevo unos días programando un script en python con la librería Pyautogui, planeando subirlo a un servidor para tenerlo corriendo las 24 horas. Hoy por fin lo he terminado y al subirlo me he topado con que no funciona, he creado otro archivo poniendo este simple script para ver si el problema era mi código

```
cords = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("settings/upload.png")
pyautogui.moveTo(cords)
pyautogui.click()
```

Pero parece que no es mi código.
El software que utilizo para conectarme es el predeterminado de windows: `Conexión a Escritorio Remoto`.
¿Qué puedo hacer?
Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Algún error por consola?

Comment: @Christian nada, completa el programa pero clicka en el sitio en el que estaba

Comment: la ruta de la imagen es correcta?

Comment: @Christian sí, sin duda

Comment: Para mi si está ocurriendo algún error. No se si es posible desde RDP, pero probaste con iniciar tu programa con cmd? es decir escribir en el cmd eldirectoriodetuscript/script.py para ver si te muestra un error en consola.

Comment: Capaz que el directorio de trabajo, que habitualmente está en la carpeta del script, está en otra parte y por eso no encuentra la imagen.

Comment: @DanteS. mi programa está siendo iniciado desde el cmd (abriéndolo en el propio directorio) Estuve leyendo y parece que hay un problema por ser RDP y recomiendan conexiones como tightvnc pero tampoco me funcionó